# VHDL: Type of "variable" is incompatible with type of <=

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Could some explain why i get syntax error with this piece of code..

```
An <= "1110" when anode = "00" else
AN <= "1101" when anode = "01" else
An <= "1011" when anode = "10" else 
An <= "0111" when anode = "11";

segment <= counter_1r    when anode = "00" else
segment <= counter_10r   when anode = "01" else
segment <= counter_100r  when anode = "10" else
segment <= counter_1000r When anode = "11";
```

it says

```
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 181. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 182. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 183. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 181. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 182. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 183. Type of An is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 186. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 187. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 188. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 186. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 187. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800 - "C:/.Xilinx/Stopur/main.vhd" Line 188. Type of segment is incompatible with type of <=.
```

Which i Don't understand, because In my code i've set all the affected element in my entity to be output, they are all using the same type.

```
PORT(
    CLK: in std_logic;
--  LED: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
--  Switch: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Segment: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
    AN: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) 
);
end Main;

architecture Behavioral of Main is
    signal counter_1000:  integer range 0 to 9;
    signal counter_100:   integer range 0 to 9;
    signal counter_10:    integer range 0 to 9;
    signal counter_1:     integer range 0 to 9;
    signal counter_1r:    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal counter_10r:   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal counter_100r:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal counter_1000r: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal prescaler:     integer range 0 to 50000000;
    signal limit:         integer range 0 to 50000000;
    signal Anode:         std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
```

Comment: What were you expecting these code fragments to do?

Comment: Segment= counter_1r and AN = "1101" when the anode = "00".. and so on..

Comment: Comparisons or assignments? Signal assignment is `<=`, but in an expression, `<=` is a relational comparison operator.

Comment: I am going to assign segment and An certain values when the anode has certain values.

Comment: Then I think the "named association" token `=>` should be signal assignment `<=`.

Comment: Having watched you ask several questions over the last several days you strike me as someone who can use a bit more exposure to something authoritative describing the VHDL language.  You could try the University of Pennsylvania [VHDL Primer](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/vhdl_primer.html), which gives examples without focusing on the language used to describe VHDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why you get the error message, look at your code like this:

```
An <= "1110" when anode = "00" else (AN <= "1101")....
```

The `else` clause will be compiled as a comparison of `AN` with `1101` to see if it's less-than-or-equal-to.  Which is of type `boolean`, which is incompatible with the type of `An`, a vector.  (I wish VHDL hadn't picked `<=` as an assignment operator, but there we are!)

The syntax you need is more like this (note the lack of `<=` on the other lines)

```
An <= "1110" when anode = "00" else
      "1101" when anode = "01" else
      "1011" when anode = "10" else    
      "0111" when anode = "11" else
      null;
```

Comment: it's saying that An and segment is incompatible with <=. both are in my entity sat to be out. ??

Answer (score 2):

Conditional Signal Assignment (outside of a process) is written as:

```
An <=
    "1110" when anode = "00" else
    "1101" when anode = "01" else
    "1011" when anode = "10" else 
    "0111" when anode = "11" else
    "0000";

segment <=
    counter_1r    when anode = "00" else
    counter_10r   when anode = "01" else
    counter_100r  when anode = "10" else
    counter_1000r When anode = "11" else
    "00000000";
```

Inside of a process, you will either need to use an **`if`** statement or a **`case`** statement.