# HDLParsers:800 Type of "**" is incompatible with type of "**"

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, xilinx-ise

```
entity address_decoder is
PORT(address : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 0 to 3 );
  decoded_address : out integer range 0 to 15);
end address_decoder;

architecture dataflow of address_decoder is
begin
PROCESS(address)
begin
    if address = "0000" then decoded_address <= '0';
    elsif address = "0001" then decoded_address <= '1';
    elsif address = "0010" then decoded_address <= '2';
    elsif address = "0011" then decoded_address <= '3';
    elsif address = "0100" then decoded_address <= '4';
```

This is the error which is coming

ERROR:HDLParsers:800  Type of decoded_address is incompatible with type of '0'.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800   Type of decoded_address is incompatible with type of '1'.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800   Type of decoded_address is incompatible with type of '2'.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800   Type of decoded_address is incompatible with type of '3'.
ERROR:HDLParsers:800   Type of decoded_address is incompatible with type of '4'.

Is it because the address and decoded_address are two different data types? Any idea on how to get rid of this error ?

Comment: It's not because address and decoded_address are different types, its because decoded_address and '1', '2', '3' and '4' are different types: you are trying to assign a character to an integer signal.

Comment: remove the single quotations from '0', '1', '2', '3' and '4'.  The type of decoded_address is integer to which you try to assign character literals. Assign numeric literals compatible with the range constraint of decoded_address instead. In general it's good working practice to analyze a design specification in either ISIM or Modelsim before XST, where the error messages can sometimes lack the clarity of this one.

Comment: @DavidKoontz: Your comment addresses the exact issue in the question, so wouldn't it be better to post this as an answer instead of a comment, so others can see that the question has an answer, and it may then be properly closed ?

Comment: Your component is doing a simple type conversion for binary encoded numbers. This can be rewritten so a single line: `decoded_address <= to_integer(unsigned(address));` So if your component has now only one line of code, you should spare it.

Comment: removing the single quotes actually helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is provided because the other 7 occurrences of `ERROR:HDLParsers:800` on Stackoverflow don't involve literals assigned to integer types, and Morten thinks an actual answer to the question may be valuable. The closest matching question with an answer (See [VHDL: Type of “variable” is incompatible with type of <=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282539/vhdl-type-of-variable-is-incompatible-with-type-of)) involves an integer assignment target with a bit string literal value).

In this if statement (missing and end if):

```
if address = "0000" then decoded_address <= '0';
elsif address = "0001" then decoded_address <= '1';
elsif address = "0010" then decoded_address <= '2';
elsif address = "0011" then decoded_address <= '3';
elsif address = "0100" then decoded_address <= '4';
```

The if statement portion shown should look like:

```
if address = "0000" then decoded_address <= 0;
elsif address = "0001" then decoded_address <= 1;
elsif address = "0010" then decoded_address <= 2;
elsif address = "0011" then decoded_address <= 3;
elsif address = "0100" then decoded_address <= 4;
```

There's a type mismatch between decode_address which is declared as a constrained integer with a range of 0 to 15 and the character literals '0', '1', '2', '3' and '4'.

The corrected if statement port assigns numeric literals (which are compatible with type integer) to decoded_address. Note that all five values fall within the range constraint of decode_address.

Answer (score 0):

Also except @David Koontz answer, you can use case statement instead.

`case address is
    when "0000" => decoded_address <= 0;
    when "0001" => decoded_address <= 1;
    when "0010" => decoded_address <= 2;
    when "0011" => decoded_address <= 3;
    when others => decoded_address <= 4;
end case;`

and never forgot to cover all the conditions.

---

btw, I don't know if it is a lecture assignment or not but you can use

`decoded_address <= to_integer(unsigned(address));`

of course you need to add
`use ieee.numeric_std.all`